# Does Cache Directory gets deleted when upgrading iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

I would like to know whether the Cache directory gets deleted when upgrading iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no clear answer for this in the  documentation. It can  be purged when the device gets low on disk space or performing a full restoration.

> Application_Home/Library/Caches
>
> Use this directory to write any application-specific support files
>   that you want to persist between launches of the application or during
>   application updates. Your application is generally responsible for
>   adding and removing these files. It should also be able to re-create
>   these files as needed because iTunes removes them during a full
>   restoration of the device.